# Sending data from raspberry pi to iPhone using bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to the raspberry pi to iPhone using bluetooth. The bluetooth device in the PI is working fine. I could pair it with my MAC. However, one point which is noticed is that the device type is unknown (strange), also when I try to search for it using the iphone, it doesn't appear on list. 
Could it be due to some missing profiles? How can i connect the iphone to the PI and send data from PI to iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

If it works on your Mac then their shouldn’t be any reason why it doesn’t work on your phone. Did you download the required apps? Maybe didn’t create the SSH connection?

Comment: do you recommend a bluetooth app on the iphone that i can use for testing?